# Certain Elements not effected by z-index using after pseudoclass

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position, z-index

So I'm creating a landing page with a 100vh image that has a faded white overlay, using the following:

```css
#showcase {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('../img/showcase.jpeg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

#showcase:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(#eee, 0.7);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section id="showcase">
  <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Test text</h1>
  <a href="#">DO SOMETING</a>
</section>
```

It works a treat expect for when I try add a button or anchor tag to the content of the div I can't seem to click or highlight it. Text in h tag and the image can be highlighted fine

Comment: Please can you edit the code to show the div you are having trouble with - there is no div

Comment: the negative z-index on #showcase is the only problem here

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `z-index:-2` from the parent and then position the child with a higher `z-index`

```css
#showcase {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  /*  z-index: -2; -- remove  this */
}

#showcase:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

#showcase * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="showcase">
  <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Test text</h1>
  <a href="#">DO SOMETING</a>
</section>
```

Comment: it's better to keep a z-index on the parent element (0 or higher) to create a stacking context so that all the child element are placed inside that stacking context. Of course there is no difference in this case but we may notice it when having more elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just `z-index` issue.

```
#showcase {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url(../img/showcase.jpeg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
   /* z-index: -2; Remove this line*/
}
```